# Need to apply multiple themes to react story book

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, storybook, nextjs-storybook

We have been using react storybook in my projects. As part of design upgradation, we are creating new components without disturbing the existing components.
old stories are in **mpg-component** folder for new component stories we have created **mpg-component-new**.
our preview js decorator is defined as below.

```
 export const decorators = [
  (Story) => (
    <div class="mpg-component-container">
      <Story />
    </div>
  ),
];
```

In my case, I would like to apply a different root class for mpg-component-new.
As I need to change a few designs for the newly added components.
Is there any way to apply different classes for the mpg-component and mpg-component-new.
Please suggest.